# If a given RegisterClassEx() call is successful once, can I assume it always will be?

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling, initialization

**Out of curiosity:**

In my `wWinMain()` entry point I am filling a `WNDCLASSEX` struct that I am subsequently passing to `RegisterClassEx()`. This is the first thing being done in WinMain, and it looks like this:

```
WNDCLASSEX windowConfig = {0};

windowConfig.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
windowConfig.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
windowConfig.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
windowConfig.hInstance = hInstance;
windowConfig.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
windowConfig.lpszClassName = L"Title";

if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowConfig))
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "RegisterClassEx failed for no apparent reason", NULL, NULL);
    return FALSE;
}
```

If this configuration runs fine once, will it ever *not*? Could one - given that the parameters are not changed - for all practical purposes just assume that registering the class will always be successful and skip the check? In other words, just

```
RegisterClassEx(&windowConfig);
```

..and move on?

What can fail?

Comment: No, you cannot assume this.  Life has *not* gotten any easier with anti-malware patching the operating system and a never-ending raft of utilities that seem to make your life easier but actually inject a DLL into every process to get their job done.

Whether you want to generate a meaningful diagnostic when such shovelware corrupts the state of the process so badly to make this code fail is up to you.  You can count on most users calling *you* first.  If there's nothing to look at then you'll of course have a hard time pushing it off to whomever is really responsible for it.

Comment: Interesting. Would we be able to know more specifically what would make such DLL injections to cause our class registration to fail?

Comment: @d7samurai: From personal experience, the kind of people who come up with DLL injection as a solution typically aren't the brightest developers. I've disassembled one such DLL that contained unused bits of unrelated Microsoft sample code, complete with entry points!

Answer (score 3):

It consumes system resources so in theory, in an exhausted system, it may fail (in that case `LoadCursor` will probably fail first)

Comment: But in such a scenario, wouldn't _anything_ and everything fail anyway (i.e. no point testing the result of the `RegisterClassEx` call specifically)?

Comment: It can be argued upon endlessly. What if it fails because some other developer changed the initialization of `windowConfig`? You can save him/her valuable time debugging the error.

Comment: I stated in my question that the parameters are not changed.

Comment: If everything stays the same, IMHO it's safe to assume it will not fail. Having said that, I'd still check the return value (for the reason mentioned above; @Xearinox gave a better reason).

Comment: This is a thought experiment to examine this specific case for real problems / reasons to check the return value, rather than to confirm "good practices". We all agree on those. Xearinox' reason is not valid in the context specified in my question because it will not cause a fail and is therefore redundant.

Comment: @d7samurai: Updated answer with context your question.

Answer (score 1):

RegisterClass(Ex) may fails if class is already registred.  Etc. some dll loaded by your process uses class L "Title"  So your window will not be created. Always (!) use properly error checking.

UPDATE: I forgot mention that RegisterClass(Ex) may fails, if global atom table is leaked and/or full.

Comment: So the `lpszClassName` is the _only_ thing that identifies a window class across the whole operating system? How can any program be started with multiple instances then?

Comment: My mistake, I rewrite answer. Thanks for response.

Comment: According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/18/409205.aspx), the class name does not matter even within the same process, as the windows are identified by their instance handles. Quote: "This is why it is okay if multiple DLLs all register a class called "MyClass"; the instance handle is used to tell them apart."

Comment: Yes. But class may have CS_GLOBALCLASS style. Call InitCommonControlsEx and try register "Edit" class.

Comment: I dont want be rude, maybe my answer is not 100% accurate. Buy your question was about fail RegisterClassEx. Answer is: Yes, may fail. PERIOD.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that and it works fine. I don't understand why it should matter that some other class is global - my class is still registered with an instance handle that makes it unique. I find it _very_ hard to believe that IDs this central to the operating system is based on string values alone.

Comment: I dont understand how you want register some class twice?

Comment: I don't. You are the one that brought that up.

Comment: Again. you register class - success. And then you assume that again will be success, right? This is mistake!!!

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I only register the class once in the program code, of course! The question is about whether there are circumstances where  `RegisterClassEx()` can fail at a later time, when _starting the application_, after it is known that it has been successful before.

Comment: I wrote answer: Class may be registred. Example: Register class in dll, load dll to the app. Close app. You forgot unregister class. Run app again. See result. Of course this is simplified scenario.

Comment: I don't have time to write a DLL just to test that right now (besides my question is clearly related to the specified context, WinMain). But I am sure it will work fine, too. Why? Because you always have to supply the _instance handle_ when registering a class. That's the whole point of the instance handle - to make the registration unique. And the instance handle is unique for every process, including DLLs.

Comment: So error 1410 dont exists? If dont believe my answer, dont check errors. Good night. PS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/20/763727.aspx

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is a case where if you load a DLL that registers a class and then unload the DLL, but forget to unregister the class and then reload the same DLL again and it happens to get the exact same base address / instance handle as before and tries to register the same class again - you will get an error. Correct. However, if you look at my question, you will see that this is not about registering classes from DLLs, but from the WinMain entry point of the application, where that [very particular] situation does not apply.